# No qualifying bean of type HandlerExceptionResolver available error in SpringBoot Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I've been trying to create a test enviroment for my project. As newbie, I've found out that - in testing - debugging is a pretty convoluted process, especially if you have a moderately large project to begin with.

Inside my test folder I have a resource folder with an import.sql and an application-test.yaml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
 
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:nameOfTheDB;Mode=Oracle
    username: sa
    password:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    allow-circular-references: true
  sql:
    init:
      platform: h2
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
server:
  port: 8090
```

I have a simple ApplicationTest where I just load the context:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

and a RepositoryTest class to test the persistence layer.

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RepositoryTest {


   @Autowired
    private UserRepository underTest;
    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        underTest.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void shoudBePresent() {
        // given
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(10L);
        user.setFirstName("first");
        user.setLastName("last");;
        underTest.save(user);

        // when
        Optional<User> expected = underTest.findById(10L);

        // then
        assertThat(expected.isPresent()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

ApplicationTest's tests run smoothly but once I try to run RepositoryTest I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")}
```

What does it mean?
I have this resolver inside a requestFilter in my config folder:

```
@Component
public class RequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;




    public RequestFilter(UserService userService,
                            @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver resolver) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            [code called every request...]
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't understand why this block of code affects my persistance layer, doesn't doFilterInternal gets called every time there is a request to a given endpoint?
I can't really figure out why it gets called inside my unit test.

I understand I might be missing crutial infos but bear in mind I'm pretty new to testing with SpringBoot (I've been trying to solve this particular issue for about 2-3 days) so any educational resource about the whole SpringBoot testing architecture is much appreciated. I'd like to learn how to test the proper way, right now this feels like black magic.

Comment: Have you define `HandlerExceptionResolver` as a bean somewhere in your code?

Comment: @HarryCoder nope. Only reference is there, inside the filter.

Answer (score 0):

`HandlerExceptionResolver` is an interface and here you have not provided any implementation as a bean to help `Spring` manage it for you. You can't instantiate an interface at first.

You have 3 options:

1. Use an implementation of `HandlerExceptionResolver` and configure it as a bean in a configuration file:

   ```
   @Bean
   public HandlerExceptionResolver createDefaultHandlerExceptionResolver() {
       return new DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver();
   }
   ```
2. Define your own implementation, by adding an annotation like `@Component` to tell `Spring` that it is a bean to be included into the Context:

   ```
   @Component
   class RestResponseStatusExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. You can use a `@ControllerAdvice` or a `@RestControllerAdvice`

Take a look on those links for more details: [here](https://farzinpashaeee.medium.com/spring-boot-exception-handling-handlerexceptionresolver-11c75ffdf5d6) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)